# ruboto Setup with Windows 8, apache ant not found

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, ruboto

Hi I am trying to setup Ruboto on my Windows 8 and getting the following error even if say yes to download and install Apache via command prompt. Any help is appreciated

```
C:\>ruboto setup
Java runtime             : Found
Java Compiler            : Found
Apache ANT               : Not found
Android Package Installer: Not found
Android Emulator         : Not found
Intel HAXM               : Not found
Android SDK Command adb  : Not found
Android SDK Command dx   : Not found
Platform SDK android-15  : Not found

!!! Ruboto setup is NOT OK !!!

Apache ANT was not found.
Would you like to download and install it? (Y/n): y    
Downloading...
Installing apache-ant-1.9.0-bin.tar.gz...
F, [2014-10-05T09:58:23.048000 #15164] FATAL -- : not in gzip format (Zlib::Gzip
File::Error)
org/jruby/ext/zlib/JZlibRubyGzipReader.java:156:in `initialize'
org/jruby/ext/zlib/JZlibRubyGzipReader.java:85:in `new'
org/jruby/ext/zlib/JZlibRubyGzipReader.java:105:in `open'
```

Answer (score 0):

download [`ant` your self](http://apache.cs.utah.edu//ant/binaries/apache-ant-1.9.4-bin.zip), and unzip to folder "c:\ant" , and udpate PATH with `set PATH=c:\ant\bin;%PATH%"` , now rerun `ruboto setup`

you may want to update your system path in windows, so the next time you open a cmd prompt you dont have to add `ant` path.